# How to use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async right?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.0, async-await

I use the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` [package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) in a project and this project is a referenced by another project that does not use async features.

Now I get this error warning when I compile the solution (or only the second project):

> The primary reference "XYZ.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "XYZ.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

I use in both projects this app.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:bcl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:bcl">
      <dependentAssembly bcl:name="System.Runtime">
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.16.0" newVersion="2.5.16.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.16.0" newVersion="2.5.16.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I don't want to reference the async package dlls.

I can't use .Net 4.5 target. It must be .Net 4.

Target Framework for all projects: .NET Framework 4

Comment: What are target frameworks for either projects?

Comment: @ToniPetrina Target Framework for all projects is ".NET Framework 4"

Comment: Strange, I've had no problems in referencing assemblies using that package. Did you add Microsoft.Bcl.Async to both projects?

Comment: @ToniPetrina That's what I don't want to. In the second project no async feature is used. Is this not possible?

Comment: I have a similar problem in my 4.0 project and it breaks code analysis with CA0060, which cannot be suppressed. I've had to disable CA for now, but plan on looking into this in greater detail later.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Summary**:

There's a couple of workarounds available to you:

1. Install the *Microsoft.Bcl.Async* package to the referencing project.
2. Install the *Microsoft.Bcl.Build* package to the referencing project. This contains the actual fix, and is solely a build-time dependency. When you do this, you must have the appropriate binding redirects in the project's App.Config (such as what you've listed above) - regardless of whether it is a class library, web project or an executable.
3. If you don't want a dependency on any package, grab the contents of the PropertyGroup element within Microsoft.Bcl.targets file (installed with Microsoft.Bcl.Build), and insert it at the bottom of the referencing project after the last Import element.

**Note:** Which ever option you choose above, when you ship a library that takes a dependency on Microsoft.Bcl.Async (as with the old Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack), you must ship those binaries (System.Runtime, System.Threading.Tasks, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.*) with the application/package that uses your library.

**Long story**:

As Peter pointed out this is a known issue that only occurs for Microsoft.Bcl.Async and not Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack, due to the way they are designed.

Part of the design of Microsoft.Bcl.Async was to backport (via a NuGet package) some new .NET 4.5 assemblies (System.Runtime, System.Threading.Tasks) so that they would run on 4.0. MSBuild does not like this, and it causes it to believe that the referencing library has taken a dependency on an assembly from a newer framework version. The workaround in Microsoft.Bcl.Build package fixes this.

Comment: thx for your reply, i will check the second and third workaround tomorrow (german time)...

Comment: What are the "appropriate binding redirects"?

Comment: Copy the same binding redirects that NuGet adds to the App.Config. It's entirely dependent on the version of the package.

Comment: @DavidKean can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361526/xamarin-mac-4-5-with-bcl-async-release-compile-failes-to-resolve-system-threadin

Answer (score 4):

Use [Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 11](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack) instead.

`Install-Package Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack`

If you prefer to use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async prerelease, you'll have to add it to all the projects.  Next release of Bcl.Async should have improved messaging to better detail that.

If you're using VS 2010, the only thing that I know of that gives you async/wait is the AsyncCTP; so, it doesn't make sense to use Microsoft.Bcl.Async in VS 2010.

## update:

W.R.T to Microsoft.Bcl.Async:  The issue around the MSB warning ("cannot be resolved...indirect dependency..." is known and being addressed.  In some future update (to MSBuild and Microsoft.Bcl.Async) this will be fixed and you *won't* have to include Microsoft.Bcl.Async in both projects.

Comment: "This pack requires Visual Studio 11 and will not work with Visual Studio 2010" Unfortunately, I'm on 2010, but OP sounds as though is on 2012.

Comment: Yep,  Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 11 is "for Visual Studio 11" aka Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Added some updates based on information received from Microsoft.

Comment: @PeterRitchie thx for your answer, but we can't use this package, because we need the fixed issues in the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx (we want using vs2012)

Comment: @punker76 Then you'll have to add a reference to both projects until the issue is resolved in a future update.

Comment: @PeterRitchie That was exactly what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991706/there-is-a-bcl-async-library-only-to-net-4

Comment: @KentBoogaart You can use it from VS 2010 as long as you have .net 4.5 installed and set the MSBuild Property [`<UseHostCompilerIfAvailable Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)'=='' Or $(VisualStudioVersion) &lt; 11 ">false</UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2008/06/11/a-tale-of-two-compilers.aspx#8593305). You might want to disable Intellisense and automatic indentation ;-).