# Deploying Microsoft.Bcl.Async w/ Clickonce

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, base-class-library

I have a VB.NET application that's crashing with the following error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.5.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.5.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

I'm trying to use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async library. I've installed it via Nuget on the project that actually uses Async/Await calls and the project that references it. Everything works perfectly on my computer, but when I publish and test on another computer, my program crashes when I try to use the portion of it that's using Async/Await.

System.Threading.Tasks is referenced in both projects with Copy Local set to true. Microsoft.Threading.Tasks is referenced in both projects with Copy Local set to true. I've seen [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551953/how-to-use-the-microsoft-bcl-async-right) about this and it's installed in the relevant projects. These are the lines contained in my app.config file:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

What am I missing with setting this up? Please let me know if you need more info. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I found a workaround posted on the project site:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx

Resolution

This occurs because ClickOnce fails to deploy certain required assemblies. As a workaround, do the following:

1.Right-click on the project and choose Add Existing Item

2.Browse to the Microsoft.Bcl net40 package folder

3.In the File name text box enter *.*

4.Holding CTRL, select System.Runtime.dll and System.Threading.Tasks.dll

5.Click the down-arrow next to the Add button and choose Add as Link

6.In Solution Explorer, holding CTRL select System.Runtime.dll and System.Threading.Taks.dll

7.Right-click the selection, choose Properties and change Copy to Output Directory to Copy always

8.Republish

Answer (score 1):

Click once will only include 3 main DLL's `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll`, `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll`, and `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll`

[image]

However, there are some more DLL's that are two more dependencies that are added when you add the nuget package that are not included in the distributable `System.Runtime.dll` and `System.Threading.Tasks.dll` You can see that the `Path` property for those two refrences are inside your project, not in the normal location.

[image]

I am not entirely sure how to fix it, but at least now you know what the problem is.

Comment: I see `System.Runtime.dll` and `System.Threading.Tasks.dll` in my list of references. What is the "normal" location vs "not the normal" location?

Comment: The normal location would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\ ` the NuGet package needs to replace those two assemblies with it's local copy, and that is why it uses those special dll's.