# Xamarin.Mac 4.5 with BCL Async release compile fails to resolve System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, base-class-library

I have been using .NET 4.5 in Xamarin Studio with portable libraries and a Xamarin.Mac project. When the Xamarin.Mac project is set to .NET 4.5 and Microsoft Async is added via nuget, compile in Debug will succeed but Release/AppStore will fail with

> error MM2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks,

In this case, it is unnecessary to add the dlls (System.Threading.Tasks and System.Runtime) from BCL because they are already in .NET 4.5. If you switch to .NET 4.0 it will work, but I have a lot of code already in .NET 4.5 that cannot be reversed because of other dependencies.

Somehow, BCL is not recognizing the Xamarin.Mac .NET 4.5 project as .NET 4.5 and still requiring the dlls.

To replicate:

1. Create a new Xamarin.Mac project
2. Set it to .NET 4.5
3. Use nuget to fetch Microsoft Async (notice correctly it does not pull in System.Threading.Tasks or System.Runtime)
4. Switch to Release
5. Compile

How does BCL know if .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5 is used? Maybe there is something I can declare in the csproj to make it recognize that System.Threading.Tasks (and System.Runtime) is already included. Or maybe some Environment variable? Or...?

**Note.** It is possible to reference the System.Threading.Tasks ans System.Runtime from the net40 nuget folder. And in the test project, this actually works - though it complains about "The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from`mscorlib.dll'" However, in my case I have a portable library which uses EventArgs and the build fails with error CS1684: Reference to type `System.EventArgs' claims it is defined assembly`System.Runtime - which of course it isn't.

Comment: Why do you need Microsoft Async? Xamarin itself supports async-await.

Comment: The portable library requires it -

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well Xamarin.Mac supports PCLs.  You can try to add an app.config with binding redirects, similar to what is described here: http://motzcod.es/post/78863496592/portable-class-libraries-httpclient-so-happy

Otherwise, I'd suggest filing a bug with Xamarin.

Comment: How does BCL know when to ask for System.Threading.Tasks and when not to? It certainly does not need it or app.config binding when using BCL Async on a .NET 4.5 project in Visual Studio. I could add a binding redirect, but it would lead to the problem with EventArgs stated above. The point actually is that the project should not need those dlls at all, yet it is being forced to have them.

Comment: If I add the System.Threading.Tasks and System.Runtime from the net40 BCL lib, it will have the effect of pointing just to these. Suddenly EventArgs in PCL, which is in System.Runtime, no longer resolves properly.

Comment: @tofutim The lib/net45 folder in the Microsoft.Bcl NuGet package is empty.  That's how the package indicates that those references aren't needed in .NET 4.5.  Xamarin.Mac uses a different framework identifier, so it's probably selecting one of the portable folders (which NuGet knows are automatically compatible with Xamarin platforms).  Simply deleting the references from the Xamarin.Mac project may help fix the issue.

Comment: Daniel, I suspect this is a Xamarin.Mac in .NET 4.5 bug. I was just able to create a similar bug without BCL. Will keep you posted.